# Como posso somar os valores idênticos da coluna de um data frame?

Tags: r

A coluna possui valores como: 1, 2, 3, NA.
Preciso agrupar os que são iguais.
Por exemplo, se tiver 4(1)s, a nova tabela vai ter um linha com o valor 4 representando a quantidade de 1s.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá, Bruno. Você quer considerar na soma as linhas, as colunas ou o data.frame todo? No título você pede uma ação e na descrição pede outra. O que você precisa fazer? Edite sua pergunta para que possamos ajudar.

Comment: Tente `tbl <- table(x);tbl <- data.frame(value = names(tbl), count = unclass(tbl))`.

Answer (score 5):

Você pode fazer algo assim:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4, NA))

df
    x
1   1
2   1
3   2
4   2
5   2
6   3
7   3
8   3
9   4
10  4
11 NA


library(dplyr)

df %>% 
   group_by(x) %>% 
   summarise(sum(x))
# A tibble: 5 x 2
      x `sum(x)`
  <dbl>    <dbl>
1     1        2
2     2        6
3     3        9
4     4        8
5    NA       NA
```